# Spring Security login with UserDetailsService and Java config

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to add login functionality with a database lookup with Spring Security, and I am really struggling. I want to look up the user by implementing the `UserDetailsService` interface. I have read a ton of documentation and Googled for hours, but I am still stuck. Most of the examples that I could find are using XML, so maybe my problems are related to converting those to Java configuration.

**UserDetailsService**

```
@Service
public class AccountServiceImpl implements AccountService { // AccountService implements UserDetailsService
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        // The email variable is always ''

        List<GrantedAuthority> authList = new ArrayList<>();
        authList.add(new Role("ROLE_USER")); // Role implements GrantedAuthority

        return new User("test@example.com", "password", true, true, true, true, authList);
    }
}
```

**Security config**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private LogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;


    @Override
    @Bean
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        // This bean is required for using method security annotations
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login/process")
                .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/", false)
                .and()
                //.userDetailsService(this.accountService)
                .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessHandler(this.logoutSuccessHandler)
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .and()
                // Permissions here
                .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("test@example.com").password("password").roles("USER");
    }

    /*@Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                //.userDetailsService(this.accountService);
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("test@example.com").password("password").roles("USER").and()
                .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }*/

    /*@Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(this.accountService);
        return provider;
    }*/
}
```

As you can see, there is a bunch of outcommented code, which are just some of the things I tried to make it work. I also tried with simple in-memory authentication, but that didn't work either.

**login.jsp**

```
<form action="/login/process" method="POST">
    <input name="j_username" id="j_username" type="text" />
    <input name="j_password" id="j_password" type="password" />

    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

**Debug**

```
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Request is to process authentication

DEBUG org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider

DEBUG org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider - User '' not found

DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials

DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Updated SecurityContextHolder to contain null Authentication
```

The above seems to always be the case for all of the configurations that I tried. I am not even sure why the `DaoAuthenticationProvider` is used, even if I try to override it; I guess it's a default. For some of the configuration above, my `UserDetailsService` implementation gets called, but with an empty string as the parameter. Also, even if I return a hard coded `UserDetails` object with the same credentials as the ones I entered in my form, the authentication still fails, and I get redirected back to `/login?error=true`.

What am I doing wrong here? Please inform me about my mistakes or provide a simple example using Java configuration. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure that's your problem, but according to http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-form you need to add "permitAll()" to allow access to your login URLs

Comment: @Nitek Thanks. `/login` is permitted. I just kept it out of the question for brevity. The permissions should all be OK - I have seen no indications that this should be the problem.

Comment: rename `j_username` to `username` and `j_password` to `password` or change the `username` and `password` name properties. The default names changed when using java based config. Currently no username will be ever passed on to any authentication mechanism. I also assume that where you wrote `UserDetails` you actually ment `UserDetailsService`!?

Comment: Reading further on this page:"
The username must be present as the HTTP parameter named username
The password must be present as the HTTP parameter named password" which means your form fields are namend incorrectly

Comment: Argh! I was actually thinking of testing that, but seeing that everyone else was using `j_*` as the input names, I didn't think much of it. Yeah, that was embarrassing! Nevertheless, it solved the problem, so thank you very much. Please write an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using Spring Security with Java based configuration the name of the request parameters are `username` and `password` and not `j_username` and `j_password` anymore.

You can either fix your login form

```
<form action="/login/process" method="POST">
    <input name="username" id="j_username" type="text" />
    <input name="password" id="j_password" type="password" />

    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

or adapt your configuration to use the old field names.

```
formLogin().usernameParameter("j_username").passwordParameter("j_password");
```

Either way will resolve your issue.